# Odata V4 batch request expand query is not send

Tags: odata, odata-v4

Odata V4 batch send only one request for updating . The Get method is not called automatically.

when sending batch request , expand query is missing? . can you please address to me,  What is default odata v4 behavior while performing batch with expand query?.

How to can handle expand query with batch in ODATA v4

Comment: Hey I don't quite understand your question. What exactly are you trying to do? Is this a question about the client or server side? Could you perhaps show the code you're having issues with and describe the expected result?

Comment: I realise that you might be past your issue but a clear example of where your expand clause is not being obeyed will help us to answer this